# git reflog in bare repository with core.logAllRefUpdates set true returns nothing

Tags: git, git-reflog

I have mirrored a git repository using `git clone --mirror`, then set `git config core.logAllRefUpdates true`, then later updated with `git fetch -p`.

On the server hosting the repo, if I run `git reflog` in the `repository.git` directory, I get no output.

The docs for `core.logAllRefUpdates` states that refs are placed in `$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>`, but I have no logs directory. Do I need to create it manually?

> core.logAllRefUpdates
>
> Enable the reflog. Updates to a ref  is logged to the file "$GIT_DIR/logs/", by appending the new and old SHA-1, the date/time and the reason of the update, but only when the file exists. If this configuration variable is set to true, missing "$GIT_DIR/logs/" file is automatically created for branch heads (i.e. under refs/heads/), remote refs (i.e. under refs/remotes/), note refs (i.e. under refs/notes/), and the symbolic ref HEAD. If it is set to always, then a missing reflog is automatically created for any ref under refs/.

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not have to create that directory. For bare repositories just enable the reflogs via

```
git config core.logAllRefUpdates true
```

The values `true` and `always` are supported. Then to see the reflog for a branch type

```
git reflog <branch>
```

See more details [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corelogAllRefUpdates), and the [documentation page of `git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), for other configuration options.