# Why command 'git log -g' not run correctly in git server side?

Tags: git, server-side, githooks

Localy the command git log -g --pretty=%H $refname return the hash commits of the new branch is ok but the same commmand return null when run inside the post-receive hook in server-side. If I remove '-g' option command run normally, mas if I return de option, empty result again. What the problem with the option '-g' in server-side?

I need to know which commits from a new git branch are pushed to the server so I can write their messages to the tracking tool, but for new branches post-receive hook sets oldrev to 0 the hash number and I can't list all the messages with 'oldrev..newrev'.

If the command 'git log -g --pretty=%H $refname' returns the correct new hash, I get the firts hash from new branch and can list oldrev..newrev correctly, but the command is returning null and I don't have the correct list of new commits

gitlab self-hosted::git version 2.40.1.gl2::

Comment: `-g` means `--walk-reflogs`. Most probably you don't have reflogs at the server, that's all.

Comment: in this case, my git server doesn't have or all git servers don't have reflogs?

UPDATED
I found the answer, I left it here in case it is useful for other people

"Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository."

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

thanks!

Comment: Repositories at a server are bare repos, and bare repos by default don't have reflogs. You can turn them on with `git config core.logAllRefUpdates true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238919/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+bare+reflog